# How to Put a comma between the records pulled out of mysql not at end or beginning php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put a comma in between the numbers I pull out of the database , but when I do it , it sometimes put  the comma  at the end and beginning which I don’t like

I want the numbers to be  =  44123123123,44188123123,44123123123

Not  = , 44123123123,44188123123,44123123123
Or = 44123123123,44188123123,44123123123,

I have tried everything but no luck . please help see also 
Bellow is what I have tried

```
$comma =",";
while($record = $targe1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$cell = $record['cell'] ;
$company = $record['company'];
$surname = $record['surname'];

    $final_cell1 = explode(",",$record['cell']);

$final_cell = implode(",",$final_cell1).$comma;


echo $final_cell;

 }
```

I am writing  a script which sends sms it pulls out numbers and names then it sends . the bulk sms plug in for sending many  sms  at once , it requires the numbers to be separated by a comma and if there is a comma at the begging or end it ignores and no sms will be sent . any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the last comma you just need substr()

Try this:

```
while ($record = $targe1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    /* Other code */
    $cell .= $record['cell'].',';
 }

$cell= substr($cell,0,-1);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I really appreciated your effort it worked 100% I spent more than 24 hours on this . you have saved me

Answer (score 2):

Gather your numbers in a single array and use implode once to it.

```
$records_array=array();
while($record = $targe1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$records_array = $record['cell'] ;
}
$final_cell=implode(',',records_array );

echo  $final_cell;
```